# Creating, labelling and exporting tables using a loop in R

Tags: r

```
#Some Data
Sales <- data.frame(Appliance =c( "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio"),Country=c("USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK"), Year=c(2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016))

#Producing a table
SalesTable<-(table(Sales[, c("Appliance", "Year")]))

#Exporting the table
write.csv(SalesTable,"Table.csv")
```

The above produces and exports a table that summarises the number of appliances sold by year. In the original table there is also a Country column which shows in which country where the product was sold. What I want to do is insert a loop that produces the table and export specifically for each of the countries and labels the export according to the country name.

Comment: Try `SalesTable2<-(table(Sales[, c("Appliance", "Year","Country")]))`

Comment: `table(Sales[c(1,3,2)])` or even `xtabs(m~Appliance+Year+Country,cbind(Sales,m=1))` etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers posted on here, the below code answers my question:

```
#Some data
Sales <- data.frame(Appliance =c( "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio"),Country=c("USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK"), Year=c(2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016))

# Extract unique country from the data i.e. USA, Canada, UK
country<- unique(Sales$Country) 
for(i in 1:length(country)){ # Loop over the each country

# Extract Appliance and Year data for each country
a<-Sales[Sales$Country==country[i],c(1,3)]

#Make the table
data<-(table(a[, c("Appliance", "Year")]))

#Export the table as a CSV file, named according to each country.
write.csv(data,paste(country[i],"csv",sep = "."))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need for loops for that. You can use a `tidyverse` approach where you can `map` functions on your data sub-sets based on `Country`:

```
Sales <- data.frame(Appliance =c( "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio"),
                    Country=c("USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK"), 
                    Year=c(2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016))

library(tidyverse)

Results = Sales %>%
  group_by(Country = as.character(Country)) %>%                    # for each country
  nest() %>%                                                       # nest data
  mutate(Table = map(data, ~table(.[, c("Appliance", "Year")])))   # create a table using your function

# see Results table
Results

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#     Country data              Table      
#     <chr>   <list>            <list>     
#   1 USA     <tibble [12 x 2]> <S3: table>
#   2 Canada  <tibble [12 x 2]> <S3: table>
#   3 UK      <tibble [12 x 2]> <S3: table>
```

So far you've created a table (`Results`), which tells you that for each `Country` you used a subset of your dataset (stored in column `data`) to create a table (stored in column `Table`).

You can see and check those tables using `Results$Table` (see as a list) or `Results$Table[[1]]`, etc. to see each element of the list.

```
# save tables as .csv files and use the countries as file names
map2(Results$Country, Results$Table, ~write.csv(.y, paste0(.x, ".csv")))
```

This command will use the tables and the corresponding countries to create .csv files in your working directory.

Comment: Thank-you for this, it is a very good solution, I will look into tidyverse more.

Answer (score 0):

`Loop` based solution: (Don't need to store data to `table` as you can directly write to `.csv` file)

```
Sales <- data.frame(Appliance =c( "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio"),Country=c("USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK"), Year=c(2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016))

# Extract unique country from the data i.e. USA, Canada, UK
country= unique(Sales$Country) 
for(i in 1:length(country)){ # Loop over the each country
     # Extract country wise data and store Appliance and Year to each file
     write.csv(Sales[Sales$Country==country[i],c(1,3)],paste(country[i],"csv",sep = "."))
}
```

**Updated Solution**

```
library(plyr)
Sales <- data.frame(Appliance =c( "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio","Laptop", "TV", "Fridge","TV", "TV", "TV","Laptop", "Laptop", "Radio"),Country=c("USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK","USA","Canada","UK"), Year=c(2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016,2017,2016,2016,2017,2017,2016))

# Extract unique country from the data i.e. USA, Canada, UK
country= unique(Sales$Country) 
for(i in 1:length(country)){ # Loop over the each country
  # Extract country wise Appliance and Year data
  a=Sales[Sales$Country==country[i],c(1,3)]
  # Get the count for each appliances
  counts <- ddply(a, .(a$Appliance,a$Year), nrow)   
  # Name the column
  names(counts) <- c("Appliance", "Year", "Freq")  
  # Bind this count with country   
  data=cbind(country[i],counts)                     
  # Now you can write this df to .csv file (country wise .csv file)
  write.csv(data,paste(country[i],"csv",sep = "."))
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, would it be possible for the output to be as a table so that you would have the counts for appliances sold per year?

Comment: @Basil: The above solution is okay for you? Please let me know in case you need additional details.

Comment: Thank-you for this, it helped me to get to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a simpler approach to get the data in one file:

```
library(dplyr)
by_coun <- Sales %>% group_by(Country,Appliance,Year)
by_couns <- by_coun %>% summarise(n = n())
ndf=data.frame(by_couns)
ndf
# > ndf
# Country Appliance Year n
# 1  Canada    Laptop 2016 2
# 2  Canada    Laptop 2017 2
# 3  Canada        TV 2016 4
# 4  Canada        TV 2017 4
# 5      UK    Fridge 2016 4
# 6      UK     Radio 2016 4
# 7      UK        TV 2016 4
# 8     USA    Laptop 2017 8
# 9     USA        TV 2017 4

library(reshape)
ndfl <- melt(ndf, id=c("Appliance","Country","Year"), preserve=FALSE)
(res=reshape1(ndfl, list(c("Country","Appliance"),"Year"), sum))
# > (res=reshape1(ndfl, list(c("Country","Appliance"),"Year"), sum))
# Country Appliance 2016 2017
# 1  Canada    Laptop    2    2
# 2  Canada        TV    4    4
# 3      UK    Fridge    4   NA
# 4      UK     Radio    4   NA
# 5      UK        TV    4   NA
# 6     USA    Laptop   NA    8
# 7     USA        TV   NA    4
write.csv(res,"Table.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response